# .htaccess redirect from subfolder to root keeping paths

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm migrating a site so I need to redirect all content from a www.oldurl.com/subfolder to the www.newurl.com and keep all the links, for example:

```
www.oldurl.com/subfolder/subfolder2
```

needs to redirect to

```
www.newurl.com/subfolder2
```

AND

```
www.oldurl.com/subfolder/subfolder3/link.html
```

needs to redirect to

```
www.newurl.com/subfolder3/link.html
```

my .htacess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is redirecting all www.oldurl.com/subfolder to www.newurl.com/ but does not follow the old paths it just sends all request to home page

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: Hi Lin yes, I've got another RedirectMatch 301 ^/otherurl/$ http://otherurl.pt/ but is unrelated and is working just fine

Comment: For new conditions new .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

For new conditions new .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ http://www.newurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```